# Is there a way to access a JavaScript object value without using obj.key or obj['key']?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {a:5};
```

Is there a way to access the value `5` without ever using the bracket syntax `obj["a"]` or the dot syntax `obj.a` on the source code?

Comment: Why do you ask?  Are you just curious?  Or are you trying to do something?

Comment: `for ... in` is an option

Comment: @SiGanteng sort of, but you'd still end up using the bracket syntax.  I guess it's not in either form he described, though.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Ah yes, completely forgotten about having to use either bracket / dot :s.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm trying to have less syntax constructs in a language that compiles to JavaScript. That is, it would be interesting if I didn't have to implement a construct that would translate to `obj[val]`. If possible, I'd like to use a function such as `obj.get(val)`. I can't define that function previously because the language is supposed to be zero-overhead. TBH I don't think that's possible but you guys always know stuff.

Comment: @Dokkat why would your own language need an additional construct?

Comment: @ExplosionPills think translating a lispy-like language to JavaScript. The form (get obj val) translates to obj[val]. I'm wondering if I could cut that translation from the implementation of that lispy-like language, and implement "get" on the language itself.

Comment: @Dokkat I don't know whether this would help, but you could implement `Object.prototype.get = function (key) { if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) { return this[key]; } }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely ugly but I think it's what you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/q4egt/

```
var obj = {a: 5};
alert(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'a').value);
```

There are "workarounds" I guess.

Comment: Not exactly because you had to use the dot operator twice, but you got the idea.

Comment: I thought the syntax you wanted me to avoid was `.a`, not `.value`. But okay :-)

Comment: Yes, that .value is the problem. If only Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor returned the property, not another object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide a reason why you want to do it, anything goes, right? So, ugly as it is, consider:

```
var o = {a:5};
alert(
  JSON.stringify(o).replace(/^.*\"a\":([^,\"}]*).*$/,'$1') // 5
);
```

It needs to be modified to be a general solution, but you should get the idea. Much simpler to just use the property access methods provided by the language.